# How to move focus on to a Textfield after an alertView from another textField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In my add contact page, am validating my email textfield , phone number fields, etc. And am checking valid email on clicking all other textfields. So when i click on the phone number field, it will check email validity and show an alertview if email is invalid. So when i click ok button in the alertView, the cursor should go to the email textfield instead of being in the phone number field.. Can anyone help on this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in alertview's delegate method,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if([alertView isEqual:emailAlert])//emailAlert should be the instance variable
    {
       if(buttonIndex == 0)//assumes ok button index is 0
       {
             [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello friend.. i have multiple alertviews.. for displaying invalid email , invalid phone number etc. but the cursor should go to email textfield only when the invalid email alertview is displayed.. how to implement that in this alertview delegate method..

Comment: @ManojEllappan: Please find my solution

Answer (score 2):

for making any textfield first responder. and you can do this in your alertview delegate.

> [yourTxtField becomeFirstResponder];

Answer (score 1):

You can set AlertView's delegate and on click of "OK" button ,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
      if (buttonIndex == 0) {
         [txtEmail becomeFirstResponder]; // your "Email" textField will get focused
    }
}
```

Try this way.. HTH :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your view controller implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate`, and add the current class as delegate to the shown alert view. In `– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` make phone text field resign first responder and make the email text field befome first responder.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you class conforms to UIAlertViewDelegate protocol and show the alert like

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Your Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel " otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

implement the delegate method like

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)//ok button index is 0
       [textFieldEmail becomeFirstResponder];
}
```